# bluetooth Multi Player Iphone App

Tags: bluetooth

How many iphones can you connect via bluetooth using bonjour I want to create a four player iphone app

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have one Master and up to seven Slaves.

So 8 total phones.

One must be a master (server) the others must be clients.

I am currently working on an app that can connect all 7 slaves to one master.

This is what I have come up with. Also if you are wanting to create a game with multi-player needs then you may want to look into the Game Kit Api that apple provides.

Also it will only work on iphone 3.0 and up. So that is 3G, 3GS and iPhone 4 devices.

Game kit does use bonjour under the hood but handles most of that for you.

Good Hunting!